# Выброс и перехват исключения

Tags: c++

Возникает ошибка в функции в строчке где else. Кто может подсказать может я неправильно исключение выбрасываю?

```
    Abonent IEmployer::createAbonent()
{
    cout << "Input surname:";
    string surname;
    cin >> surname;
    cout << "Input name:";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Input midname:";
    string midname;
    cin >> midname;
    cout << "Input phone:";
    string phone;
    cin >> phone;
    cout << "Input year:";
    unsigned short int year;
    cin >> year;
    cout << "Input plane:";
    string plane;
    cin >> plane;
    Abonent abonent = Abonent::Abonent();
    try
    {
        if (abonent.setMidName(midname) != true && abonent.setSurname(surname) != true && abonent.setName(name) != true && abonent.setPhone(phone) != true && abonent.setPlane(plane) != true && abonent.setYear(year) != true)
            throw new exception("Error creating abonent. Try again");
        else
        {
            return abonent;
        }
    }
    catch (exception& ex)
    {
        showErrorMessage(ex.what());
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень странно вы обрабатываете исключения. Какой от него смысл если вы его тут же перехватили?

Comment: @ヒミコ так его выбрасывать должно если условие if сработает, а если не сработает должно возвращать абонента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ошибка в функции в строчке где else

Не беспокойтесь, мы уже угадали, какая возникает ошибка.

---

Вы не даете исключению выйти из функции. Поэтому путь "исключение-перехват" не возвращает из функции никакого значения и не выбрасывает исключения. Компиляторы этого не любят.

```
...
try
{
    if (abonent.setMidName(midname) != true && abonent.setSurname(surname) != true && abonent.setName(name) != true && abonent.setPhone(phone) != true && abonent.setPlane(plane) != true && abonent.setYear(year) != true)
        throw new exception("Error creating abonent. Try again");
}
catch (exception& ex)
{
    showErrorMessage(ex.what());
}
return abonent;
```

или

```
if (abonent.setMidName(midname) != true && abonent.setSurname(surname) != true && abonent.setName(name) != true && abonent.setPhone(phone) != true && abonent.setPlane(plane) != true && abonent.setYear(year) != true)
    throw new exception("Error creating abonent. Try again");
return abonent;
```

Comment: Бросаемое исключение не перехватывается.

Comment: @VTT Эта фраза что значит?

Comment: Ну вы пишете *"Вы не даете исключению выйти из функции. Поэтому путь "исключение-перехват" не возвращает из функции никакого значения и не выбрасывает исключения."*, а бросаемое исключение спокойно покидает функцию

Comment: @VTT "исключение спокойно покидает функцию" - после блока `catch`?

Comment: Да, блок catch бросаемое исключение не перехватит, ведь бросается указатель, в перехватывается ссылка